# How can I repair a circular drywall patch seam?

Tags: drywall, walls, painting

I hope someone would be kind enough to help me.

We recently had a bathroom cabinet fitted. As it required wiring to the light switch an electrician used a tool to cut holes into the wall so he could feed the cable through and connect it.

He then replaced the holes somehow (they seemingly went in and out in one piece, I have no idea how they were stuck back in) and said that all I would need to do is sand the edges and paint over them.

My problem is that I have tried sanding them (with a fairly fine sandpaper), but there is still a slight circular ridge that is still bound to be prominent and unlikely to be hidden by even a couple of coats of paint. [image: *Please see attached photo*].

I doubt I have the skill to skim the wall myself, and currently really can't afford to get someone in to do it, however I've seen a few options online that I think might be worth giving a go myself, including using a base coat, or a product such as "Everbuild Filler Coat".

I'm hoping that someone might have experience of a similar issue and be able to advise me please.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

That electrician was no plasterer.

First you need to get rid of the high spots where the paper part of the drywall is showing through, you might need to cut that out with a knife. after that you just need to fill it with plaster filler until it's flat then sand it smooth and paint.

If you light it at an extreme angle the high spots will be easily visible.

you probsbly want to use poweder based fiiller, not pre mixed joint compound,  the powder stuff sets hard quicker and shrinks less.

Comment: Respectfully disagree with using powdered ("setting") compound. It's hard to sand and get a nice feathered edge, even for a pro. Agree completely with the rest of your advice.

Comment: Thanks Jasen. I have some of that expanding foam stuff. Would that do as a filler?

Comment: no, I mean plaster-like stuff

Comment: it's only hard to sand if you use too much.

Answer (score 1):

When I poke pull holes I do similar, 200 grit paper will knock the ridges or a sanding sponge, once the ridges are down skim coat or the paper will probably show, a wide taping knife and some pre mixed mud skimmed on will work let dry and sand  then get a can of spray texture and try to match , do not use tape to block off an area as the tape will produce a line that will be noticeable , start further Back spray the area fading to the outside let it dry if it looks close paint and you are done, matching texture is difficult in a small area so adding a light texture to a larger area will hide the hole much better.

Answer (score 0):

This needs proper taping or it's likely to crack on the joint. Lay two strips of standard tape in a thin bed of joint compound and let it dry. Then skim wide and flat with a second coat. Evaluate the situation when that dries, and skim again if necessary.

Standard advice: Very little sanding should be necessary. Skim thinly with firm pressure to achieve a flat finish.